# Microsoft Sync Framework and SharePoint

Tags: sharepoint, microsoft-sync-framework

Sorry for this - propably - stupid question, but I read about the Sync Framework For Microsoft Sharepoint ([here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ee536628%28v=office.14%29.aspx)) but I could not find the SDK or sourcecode anywhere.

Does anyone know where I can find it? 
Or did I misunderstand that and you have to go and use these webservice methods?

```
GetListItemChangesWithKnowledge(String, String, XmlNode, XmlNode, String, XmlNode, String, XmlNode, XmlNode)
```

And if so, is there anyone that has a working code sample for this?

Thanks!

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Did not find a solution. But SharePoint should be avoided by developers anyway

Answer (score 0):

You can check code example here:

http://chakkaradeep.com/index.php/sharepoint-2010-lists-getlistitemchangeswithknowledge-method/

But can you please elaborate why do you want to use this as there are many other options to sync data from sharepoint to other clients and it's mainly done for synchronizing with external client apps such as SharePoint Workspace

Comment: Well this is indeed a blog post about that webmethod, but it doesn't show how you can use it using c#.
I'd like to parse the data using c# and add it to a local SQLite database. That'd be perfect for me. :)